# jQuery Hide This if button data attribute equals

Tags: jquery, this

I have the following jQuery code to check if the data-target attribute has this value.

```
if ($('.btn').data("target") === "#accordion-description"){
    alert('yes');
    $(this).hide();
}
```

The alert fires however "this" does not hide.

Here's the HTML behind it:

```
<button class="btn collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion-description" aria-expanded="false">Description</button>
```

How can I use "this" to hide the button?

Update: found the solution with:
$('.btn[data-target="#accordion-description"]').hide();

Answer (score 1):

In the context of that code, `this` doesn't identify anything in particular.  (If anything, it's the `window` object.  Which you probably can't hide, and don't want to.)

If `.btn` can identify multiple elements, you probably want to loop through them.  jQuery's `.each()` can make light work of that, and within its callback you get the benefit of `this` referring to the element.  For example:

```
$('.btn').each(function () {
    if ($(this).data("target") === "#accordion-description") {
        alert('yes');
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

(Since `$(this)` is invoked twice, you may even want to store it in a variable and just reference the variable.  Small performance improvement, it's up to you on readability.)

Or, if you *just* want to hide the elements, and the whole "alert" thing was just for testing, you don't need to overcomplicate it like this.  You can just identify the target elements in a selector and hide them:

```
$('.btn[data-target="#accordion-description"]').hide();
```